# Problem with TreeSet and Hibernate - Cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to retrieve elements from db and for some reason the hibernate and treeset are reaching the exception.

I have an entity "Ticket" with a TreeSet of "Pendencia".

**Ticket:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TICKET")
public class Ticket {
.
.
.
    @OrderBy("id")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "TICKET_PENDENCIA", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TICKET", nullable = true) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PENDENCIA", nullable = true)})
    private SortedSet<Pendencia> pendencias = new TreeSet<Pendencia>(new ComparatorPendencias());
```

**Pendencia:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PENDENCIA")
public class Pendencia implements Comparator<Pendencia> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String nome;    
    boolean checked;

    public Pendencia() {
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Pendencia(String nome) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Pendencia o1, Pendencia o2) {
        return Long.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());

    }


}
```

When i try to load from db using regular spring jpa find all:

```
@GetMapping("/tickets")
public List<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
    List<Ticket> tickets =  ticketRepository.findAll();
```

Then it's giving the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.br.tcc.workflowtrouble2020.model.Pendencia cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

Pendencia is already implementing comparator interace and the method compare.
What am I missing?

Obs: I don't want to change it to list of hashset, I want it to work using the treeset.

Comment: You're implementing `Comparator`, not `Comparable`.

Comment: You need to learn to read the stack trace. it says right here : Pendencia cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable. so making it a Comparator type wont help. You have to make it comparable type

Comment: Right.
How Should I implement compareTo in order to sort by id attribute?

Comment: So implement Comparable<T> interface. Normally you will not Comparator for any model object. Comparator is to provide a different rule of comparison different from natural sorting - defined by Comparable.